# Change affinity of process with batch script

Tags: batch, vbscript, affinity

Change affinity of process with batch script:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE /C Start /affinity 1" "E:\Lapu\CM.accdb" /x "001"
```

Unable to get the result

Comment: This command-line doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do?